# How do Christians reconcile this passage?

Tags: scriptures, logic

1. The old testament is God given
2. Yet Christians no longer follow it, for example they eat pork and changed the sabbath day from Saturday to Sunday
3. The reason for this is that Jesus told them the Old Testament has been replaced and no longer needs to be followed
4. It says in Deuteronomy (13) If a prophet, or one who foretells by dreams, appears among you and announces to you a sign or wonder, 2 and if the sign or wonder spoken of takes place, and the prophet says, “Let us follow other gods” (gods you have not known) “and let us worship them,” 3 you must not listen to the words of that prophet or dreamer. The LORD your God is testing you to find out whether you love him with all your heart and with all your soul.

(Follow other Gods includes following scriptures that disavow even a single word of the old testament)

Comment: Ah, but is there evidence (in the Old Testament for example) that "follow other gods" in fact means that? Even if there is, I don't know that all groups of Christians resolve any resulting paradox the same way. As a result, this question may be closed as being too broad.

Comment: If you look up Acts 3:13, Jesus was backed by the same God of the Old Testament. He's not promoting a new or different God.

Comment: It would not be fair to bring the new testament as a proof that the new testament replaces the old, until you prove that the new testament is allowed by the old, which according to that passage, it is not.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). It's unclear to me whether you're actually asking a question or making a statement. You also don't say what group or denomination of Christians you want an answer from. There will be various answers depending on the perspective of the particular Christian denomination. For what's on topic here, please see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Jesus is not another god. :)

Comment: Since this is about the Law, you should include the next verse... "Ye shall walk after YHVH your God, and fear him, **and keep his commandments**, and obey his voice, and ye shall serve him, and cleave unto him."

Comment: The last sentence in your question: is that your own criteria, or is that a position supported in Scripture?  If the latter, please provide the scripture that supports it.  If not, why is it in the question?

Comment: The Old Testament allows for the New, because Jeremiah 31:31-34 says Jehovah will make a new covenant. Hebrews 8:7-13 speaks of the fulfillment of Jeremiah 31:31-34.

Answer (score 2):

Christians have addressed this in various ways:

Some (a very small minority), such as [Marcion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcion_of_Sinope) challenged premise 1. - they didn't believe in the Old Testament. Most Christians have rejected this approach to the extent of labelling those who adopt it as being heretical.

A slightly bigger group (comprising the likes of [Seventh Day Adventists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seventh-day_Adventist_Church) and [Messianic Jews](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messianic_Judaism)) would take serious issue with your premise 2. - they take the Old Testament law seriously and *do* seek to follow whatever part of it that *can* still be followed (considering that the destruction of the temple has practically put paid to all the laws related to temple worship, Orthodox Jews are in the much the same boat here).

The vast majority of Christians would challenge your premise 3. as being a completely false characterization of what Jesus did and taught:

> <sup>17</sup> “Do not think that I have come to abolish the Law or the Prophets; I have not come to abolish them but to fulfill them. <sup>18</sup> For truly I tell you, until heaven and earth disappear, not the smallest letter, not the least stroke of a pen, will by any means disappear from the Law until everything is accomplished. <sup>19</sup> Therefore anyone who sets aside one of the least of these commands and teaches others accordingly will be called least in the kingdom of heaven, but whoever practices and teaches these commands will be called great in the kingdom of heaven. <sup>20</sup> For I tell you that unless your righteousness surpasses that of the Pharisees and the teachers of the law, you will certainly not enter the kingdom of heaven. - [Matthew 5:17-20 NIV](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=matt%205&version=NIV)

Additionally, many would make the point that although God is Lord over all, the Mosaic law wasn't given to humanity in general, but to the children of Israel in particular, and the vast majority of Christians are not descendants of Israel, but **gentiles** - they are, by default, *excluded* from the Mosaic Covenant therefore they are not bound by it's provisions. Of more relevance are the [commands given to Noah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Laws_of_Noah) from whom all are believed to be descended and [these provisions were actually reiterated by the early Christian Church at her first general council](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=acts%2015&version=NIV).

Your point 4. is completely moot - the Old Testament has not (except by Marcion and his ilk) been disavowed and there is therefore no direction to follow "other Gods".

Comment: Point 4 - Aren't the laws of the old testament disavowed, eg prohibition against eating pork? Or are you saying that since those commandments were incumbent on Jews, they were never intended for gentiles, and in fact they still apply to Jews?

Comment: The latter exactly - Jewish law of course applies to Jews, it doesn't apply to gentiles.

Comment: Are you saying that Jewish Christians are still required to follow the Law?

Comment: @anonymouswho If they have included themselves in that covenant they had better.The righteousness of Christ is of no avail to them-  let them find righteousness in the blood of bulls and rams if that's where they seek it.

Comment: @Andrew Do you mean a person who is born a Jew, and then becomes a Christian, no longer needs to follow the Law (and of course needs to seek the triune god). Also, and  I mean this with all sincerity, are you saying "The righteousness of Christ is of no avail to them- **let them** find righteousness in the blood of bulls and rams if that's where they seek it..." so they can go to hell to have their flesh burned forever?

Comment: This thread is leaving discussion of the question and entering doctrinal discussion. I'm happy to continue in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59131/discussion-between-andrew-and-anonymouswho).

Answer (score 1):

The law was created before Eve sinned, or she could not have broken Gods Law,

God wrote this same law on stone to people that had come out of slavery in Egypt and starts it with l am the Lord your God

Noah was not a Jew,

The prescription for eating meat was given after the flood

The Sabbbath was created and blessed on the 7th day of creation, scripture no where says it was created for the Jews

Comment: Tom, are you saying that Noah was not a Jew since he predated the covenant Abraham made with God?

Comment: That's my take on it. Can anyone show scripture to show otherwise

Answer (score 0):

In the Sermon on the Mount, Jesus says he came to fulfil the Law and the Prophets (Matt.5:17) but does He endorse them? Well if you only read to verse 20 it would seem so. However Jesus now explains what the Law is. God has not changed his mind. I know many Christians will say Jesus is merely adding to the existing Laws or something to that effect. But he repeals completely the ‘God given’ law on oaths, retaliation and divorce and finally emphasises the love behind the Law in Matt.7:12 (KJV) Therefore all things whatsoever ye would that men should do to you, do ye even so to them: for this is the law and the prophets. The greek is even more emphatic – this(οὗτος) indeed(γάρ) is(ἐστιν) the law . . . 
I believe it was no accident that Jesus took the people up the mountain to give them the correct law, symbolising Moses going up the mountain. The law had become corrupted by additions and or errors and this Sermon from God Himself should supersede any notion we have of Old Testament law.